# Using HttpModule (deprecated) with Angular 9

Tags: angular, express, upgrade, angular-services

I recently updated from Angular 4 to 9. I did the following:

1. Created new Angular 9 project, copied all code into angular 9 project
2. Updated `rxjs` (added pipes where necessary, removed concat)
3. Fixed easy to fix warnings (unused modules variables etc)
4. Installed `HttpModule` (deprecated) to eliminate errors relating to 'cannot find HTTP' errors and get my project back on track

I am now at the point where running `ng build / ng serve` does not throw any errors, and I am able to visit local host and get my landing page. However, using my old login form does not work. I keep getting a `CORS` error, though I have the following headers set in `express`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});
```

`Relevant Package Details: "@angular/core": "~9.1.4" <-- all angular components are at this point, "@angular/common": "~9.1.4", "@angular/http": "^7.2.16", "express": "^4.17.1"`

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to run an angular 9 app with the `HTTP module` as I am trying to do?  If anyone has had success with it, were there any configuration changes / was it plug and play?
2. Is it possible the CORS error could be related to using `HTTP module` rather than updating to httpClient?
3. If I have to update to `httpClientModule`, is there a tool/utility that can be used to make this update easier?

Comment: Try new http in one place and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was how I ended up resolving my upgrade problems:

1. I created an new project with angular CLI.
2. I moved all my code into the new project and then went through and fixed any exceptions one at a time.

I wish there was an easier way to do it because this was a time consuming process.  However, in the end it worked out and I was able to upgrade the entire project.

Answer (score 5):

It is not so easy to upgrade 5 major versions at one shot. You should better follow the updated [guide](https://update.angular.io/#4.0:9.0)

As for the `HttpModule`, it is deprecated and removed after v7. It is much easier to upgrade to new `HttpClientModule` than trying to make something removed working.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but one of the steps is to change the to HttpClient which is what I am asking about.  My app is running, so I believe I've taken care of most of the issues, except this 'CORS' issue - see update